# How to approach this: change lead source into 2 fields

Tags: leads, fields

We currently have around 30 values for the Lead Source field in a lead - that are propogating to the Account same field.

Marketing now wants to change that into a major lead source field ( 6 values) and 30 sub fields (2ndry-lead-source)

The selection of the child value according to the parent is easy - and not the question.

How should I approach this? what steps should I take in order to successfully split the fields?

- taking into account the repotrs/dashboards/triggers/workflows that lead source is used in?

I am not talking about a lead object - The Lead Source field will be left alone, with 6 values, and sub-fields will have the rest.

Comment: Its not clear to me if you're saying you'll have a Parent Lead Source object with 6 fields and a Child Lead Source Object with 30 fields or that you'll have One Master Lead Source Object that has 6 primary (required) fields plus 30 (secondary/optional) fields. Could you perhaps clarify this in some sort of hierarchy diagram which might help us better understand what your describing or the gist of your question regarding your options?